# Producing same random numbers in c++ and .NET

Tags: c#, c++, .net, random, random-seed

I have to port a c++ program to C#.

Random numbers are involved in the program. I have to produce exactly same random numbers in both program to get same results in testing.

In C++ I use

```
srand(1000)
...
double r = (double)rand() / (double)(RAND_MAX);
```

and in C# I use

```
private readonly Random _rnd = new Random(1000);
...
_rnd.NextDouble()
```

However programs produces different numbers despite same seed. Is there any way to produce same random numbers?

Comment: "The same randon numbers". A bit contradictory, maybe?

Comment: I'll bet something in `<random>` would, particularly something with a Mersenne Twister. I'd also bet on C# stating what you need to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially both random functions (srand vs Random) have different underlying implementations, thus you can't rely on them giving the same output. So why not provide a set of "n" numbers and feed them into your algorithm in both c++ and c# - just for testing purposes ofcourse? This way you're always certain you'll have the same amount, the same numbers and the same order.

e.g.: a file with on every line some numbers, then read it out in both c++/c# and then feed those numbers into the algorithm you're trying to "test".

(Also, what is it that you want to test here? An algorithm you wrote (the ported algorithm thus), or the "random" capabilities in both languages?
Because, depending on your answer to my questions above, the answer that would be relevant to your case might differ a lot! So could you provide us with some more context?)

Comment: this is my escape plan. If i can't find any other solution i will create a file contains a sequence of random numbers and i use it both program.

Comment: I use random numbers to assign velocity of particles. Those particles are colliding between each other and walls. Hence if the initial velocities are different, final state of the system will be different as well.

Comment: Thanks for the provided context. However, if it is just a one time thing (for testing) you could go with my suggestions, but if it's needed in both the c and the .net port at all times structurally then I'd say go with @V-X 's answer/suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know, what algorithm is used for c++ rand and c# Random class?

You can try to implement some [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) on your own. Eg. [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) algorithm is very simple and easily implementable in both languages...Just use some common parameters from the wiki page.

Comment: true indeed, but a lot of work when he only needs to "test", not? I think we'd need a bit more context to understand why he wants the same output always. I assume it's for testing, but if it's fundamental, then indeed it would be a good idea to roll your own. Or maybe use P/Invoke to a c/c++ lib that calls srand..

Comment: `class CRandom { unsigned int m_seed; CRandom(int seed){ m_seed = seed;} unsigned int Next(){ m_seed = 1664525 * m_seed + 1013904223; return m_seed;} };` This doesn't seem to me to be too much work....

Comment: yes yves is right. to implement some other things will be burden for me.

Answer (score 0):

i used this

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

as my declaration.

and this:

```
Convert.ToString(rnd.Next(1, 49))
```

as the execution when the button is pressed.

maybe you can have a useful use of this.

Greetings

Comment: But this wouldn't produce the same outputs as the srand equivalent, not?